# Artillery: How to publish artillery html report charts into Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, artillery

I am working on a requirement where I have to generate the load test report using artillery tool and publish the report stats into our Azure DevOps pipeline.

Artillery generates the report into html format and same I want to show into Azure DevOps pipeline. How can i do it?

I know Azure pipeline supports only Junit reports but still is there a way I can publish the artillery HTML report?

Comment: Hi, how about below solution? If it could help you achieve what you want, you can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930) thus other SO users can refer to know whether it is works. If not, feel free to leave comment if you still has puzzle.

Comment: yea it did makes sense to me. Thank you

Comment: glad the work around could help you. You can also vote and comment the suggestion ticket. Our Product group use that as a primary factor for driving new features.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT: Hi Merlin, Can you please tell me from where i can install this extension?

Comment: This extension could not be found from marketplace since the publisher haven’t maintained any more. You could use my github repo (I provided the link in the answer) which modified based on the previous scripts. I have change some syntax so that it would satisfied the latest grammar. You can publish as extension then use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If without any plugin or extension support, until now, the HTML report would not be compiled successfully, then [map corresponding attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#result-formats-mapping) into pipeline directly. As you know, until now, it only support the format: TRX, JUnit, NUnit2,   NUnit3, xUnit2, CTest.

As work around, you can define your customized extension. With this extension, add one new section into pipeline first, use task to publish this HTML report into this new section, then map and display its attributes into this section.

There has a sample extension can for you refer to: [vsts-publish-html-artifact](https://github.com/johnwalley/vsts-publish-html-artifact).

**Note:**

Since this extension programmed 4 years ago and no longer maintained now, also most of our official doc content has been updated with the latest grammar, such as categories and etc. I modify johnwalley's script, thus you can directly use it now. Due to my github repository: [Merlin-Extension](https://github.com/LiangMengdi/Publish-HTML-Artifacts).

You can also extend the functionality of this extension by adding scripts based on your individual needs. Refer to this doc for extension script written: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops

---

The work around I provide above can only consider as a temporarily method. Since Xml reports are too basic and html is more useful in many cases/ tools, I also looking forward to the feature for **HTML report Published in pipeline** can be expanded into Azure Devops.

Here has a [feature suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html) exists on our official forum. We can vote and comment it there to make it has a broad community impact, also will improve the Azure Devops experience. Thus our product group will consider to take this feature into our develop roadmap.